# Add/Remove Campaign Members Based on Contact List using Apex

Tags: apex, batch, contact, campaign, campaign-member

I'm having a hard time figuring out the logic for this in Apex. In C# I would just use linq.

I have an existing campaign that I want to add/remove members based on new lists of contacts.

Basically, if the campaign member is not on the contact list, I want to remove them from the campaign and if they don't exist I want to add them.

For exampled. I have an existing campaign with 500 members. I generate a new contact list using specific criteria that is 550 members. The new list has 60 new members and 10 members that need to be removed from the campaign.

Here is the batch apex I'm using now which will only add new members, but not delete members that are in the campaign, but not on the new list. I'm actually have to edit it use a comparison map instead of the if statement when adding them. Probably would be more efficient.

```
global class BatchAddToCampaign implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,  Database.Stateful
{
    //Id and Set retrieved from separate controller
    global final Id campaignId;
    global final Set<Id> qKeys;

    global BatchAddToCampaign(Id campaignId, Set<Id> qKeys){
        this.campaignId = campaignId;
        this.qKeys = qKeys;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator('Select Id From Contact Where Id In :qKeys');
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope) {
        List<CampaignMember> cm = new List<CampaignMember>();   
        Map<Id, Campaign> cmMap = new Map<Id, Campaign>([Select (Select ContactId From  CampaignMembers) From Campaign c Where Id = :campaignId]);
         for(Contact c : scope) {
             CampaignMember newCM = new CampaignMember(
             CampaignId = campaignId,
             ContactId = c.Id,
             status = 'Sent' );
                 if (!cmMap.containsKey(c.Id)) {
                     cm.add(newCM); 
                 }
         }

         try {
             Database.insert(cm); 
         } catch (DmlException ex) {
            System.Debug('Insert failed ' + ex);
         }        
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,  TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email From AsyncApexJob WhereId = :BC.getJobId()];
        // Send an email to the Apex job's submitter notifying of job completion.
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {a.CreatedBy.Email};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject('Add to Campaign ' + a.Status);
        String campaignURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + campaignId;
        mail.setPlainTextBody('The batch Apex job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems + ' batches with '+ a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures. ' + 'Link to Campaign: ' + campaignURL);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because the execute method gets called multiple times with a different part of your new list of contacts it would be difficult to do the adding and removing in the same job.  You could have the finish method launch a second batch job that does the removal.  It could have its own selection criteria and be rather straight forward

Comment: I wouldn't need to remove very many members from the campaign, it would definitely be under the governor limit, so I wouldn't need batch to do that. I could compare 2 separate maps. One for the existing contacts from the original campaign and the other for the new contacts to be added to the campaign. Question is can you compare 2 maps or maybe sets and only select unique records? I would think it's possible.

Comment: Maps will only allow one record per key so if you remove the records to delete from the maps and then combine the two maps then you will have a unique set

Comment: Thanks, let me explore that. I'm not quite sure how I would need to code the maps between the lists to compare.

Comment: Doing a bit more tinkering. I can create maps for both the current contact Ids and in the campaign and the contact Ids from the new contact list, but that still leaves out deleting (removing) the campaign members that were on the old list, but not on the new one, and vice versa. It seems that 2 new maps or lists will need to be created. One for the members to be added and one for the members to be removed. Those list will be quite small, but the only way I can see getting this list is via looping.

Comment: I think I found a solution for this. I'll post back once I test it.